# Specify virtual environment path in gunicorn config

Tags: virtualenv, gunicorn

I want to run several apps from one server. It seems logical to install gunicorn globally and configure several different services. But how to specify path to a particular app's virtual environment? I can't find a command for it in the manual.

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=myapp.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=admin
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/admin/myapp/source
ExecStart=/home/admin/.local/bin/gunicorn \
          --log-level=debug \
          --capture-output \
          --log-file /var/log/gunicorn-errors.log \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/myapp.sock \
          myapp.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Or is installing gunicorn in the virtual environment for every app is the only option?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something called **Environment** under the Service section and assign the path to your virtual env bin.

Ex:

```
[Service]
User=admin
Environment="PATH=/home/admin/venv/bin/"
```